# array output and error: invalid literal for int() with base 10

Tags: python-3.x, debugging

I am debugging the python code to get user input as an array like [89.79,55,12] and generate the output as an array [HD,D,P,F]. However, the program is not accepting the array values and showing error: invalid literal for int() with base 10.

Please help.

```
#Blank variable to store user input and GPA
totals = []letters = []
Get and store user input
print ("Please enter the grade for each student, or press q to quit")
while(True):
user_input =input("> ")
if(user_input.lower() == "q"):
    break
totals.append(user_input)
#Caclulate letter grade for each user response
for total in totals:
if int(total)<= 59:
    letters.append("F")
elif int(total) <= 69:
    letters.append("P")
elif int(total) <= 79:
    letters.append("C")
elif int(total) <= 89:
    letters.append("D")
else:
    letters.append("HD")
#Print GPA results.
print("The GPA for your students is:{}".format(letters))
```

Comment: Can you also show how you are inputting the numbers? -- is it `89<ENTER>79<ENTER>` etc?

Comment: Using the code above - this is not reproducible with the inputs being 89, 79, 55, 12, q.